# condition check in for loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop

Suppose I have a string "str". 
My for loop is as follows:

```
 for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){

    //do stuff

 }
```

question: When the condition is checked ,i < strlen(str), is the strlen(str) part calculated each time the loop runs ? Or it gets stored and is computed for the first time only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition expression in a loop will get evaluated at each and every iteration - it *has* to be that way until (ideally) the expression becomes false. So yes: `strlen(str)` will be calculated over and over again. If the string doesn't change at all, it'll be better if you store its length in a local variable.

```
int n = strlen(str);
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This will also work:

```
for (i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: thing is,on mostly all programming websites i've seen them use the strlen condition in the for loop. So we should use the variable to do that ,right ? It should give better performance, although very slightly.

Comment: @guitar_geek take a look at this [article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tips/tip/dont-use-strlen-in-a-loop-condition), it drives my point home.

Comment: If it is true that most websites put strlen in the condition, this merely validates the observation that most websites are bad sources of information.

Comment: @OscarLopez - will the compiler not take care of it ?  I read it from a book that the code optimization stage in the compilation process takes care of such things. It calculates the value and then replaces it with the calculated value, and thus it doesnot have to evaluate strlen() everytime.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. There is nothing that forces a compiler to evaluate `strlen` each time unless you introduce a reason for it, such as changing the string in the body of the loop. But if you do that, pulling `strlen` out of the loop is no longer an option. Here's [a demonstration](https://godbolt.org/g/n64muT). Perhaps it was true when the answer was posted, but this is now being pointed to by duplicates and should be updated or replaced. Though, this isn't advocating that the `strlen` should be left in the loop condition.